# R ggplot: ordering in a stacked bar chart?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, grouping, bar-chart

I have a dataframe consisting of a number of different subjects, and the percentages of grades obtained in each of them.  I can produce a percentage chart with:

```
ggplot(data=marks,aes(fill=Grades,y=Percentage,x=Subject)) + geom_bar(position="fill",stat="identity")
```

However, the letter grades I'm using include HD (High Distinction), D (Distinction), C (Credit), P (Pass), N (Fail) and a few others for withdrawn, ungraded pass etc.  The plot command automatically orders them alphabetically: C, D, HD, N, P ... whereas I want them in order of highest grade to lowest: HD, D, C, P, N, ...

How can I include that order in my ggplot function call?

Note, if it helps, the first few rows of the dataframe are:

```
   Grades Subject Percentage
1      HD    Math      24.16
2       D    Math      35.91
3       C    Math      24.16
4       P    Math      11.41
5       N    Math       4.03
6 WD-LATE    Math       0.00
```

and so on: one row for every subject and grade.

Comment: (You probably use ggplot2 over v2.2.0, so please check the answer of mr./ms. Inhabitant)

Comment: `marks$Grades <- factor(marks$Grades, c('HD', 'D', 'C', 'P', 'N','WD-LATE'))`